# Unexpected output in a C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void koaneeye(){
    static int j=0;
    int n,i=0,rev=0;
    while( scanf("%d",&n) == 1)
        koaneeye();
    while(n)
    {
        i=n%10;
        rev=rev*10+i;
        n=n/10;
    }
    printf("%d\n",rev);
}

int main() {

    koaneeye();

    return 0;
}
```

For the above program

Input: 123 223 323 423 523 623

Output: **325767891** 326 325 324 323 322 321

Why is that extra number coming?

Comment: `int n,i=0,rev=0;
    while( scanf("%d",&n) == 1)` n is uninitialised, and the "final" scanf() does not assign to it either.

Comment: A short explanation of what the code is supposed to do would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The printf statement is called one too many times.  You need to stop execution in the case that you didn't read data.  Since you are using recursion anyway, you don't need to loop:

```
if( scanf("%d",&n) != 1) return;
koaneeye();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void koaneeye(){
    static int j=0;
    int n = 0, i=0, rev=0; // HERE
    int ret = 0;
    while((ret = scanf("%d",&n)) == 1)
        koaneeye();
    if (ret != 1)
        return ;
    while(n)
    {
        i=n%10;
        rev=rev*10+i;
        n=n/10;
    }
    printf("%d\n",rev);
}

int main() {

    koaneeye();

    return 0;
}
```

Now it will be ok ! You have to initialize `n`, because:
`while( scanf("%d",&n) == 1)` will be false for your last input (which is not a number I guess). So `n` is unchanged, but `n` has a random value ! So `while(n)` could be true, and that's why you have this strange value.

Comment: Pointless. They come along, downvote cowardly and go away without any notice. Probably they'll never look at this answer again.

Comment: Won't this output `0` before the rest of the data?

Answer (score 1):

The innermost call is terminated with an invalid input.

If you detect this, you refrain from calling `koaneeye()` again, but nevertheless you continue processing that data.

As well, I think an `if` is sufficient here, because the iteration is "self-repeating".

So you should do

```
if (scanf("%d",&n) == 1) {
    // Succeeded in reading a value - call next before us.
    koaneeye();
} else {
    return; // refrain from processing bogus input from above.
}

while(n)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while( scanf("%d",&n) == 1)
    koaneeye();
```

to

```
if( scanf("%d",&n) == 1)
    koaneeye();
else
  while(n)
  {}
```